# How do I achieve the effect of `DOCTEST_CONFIG_TREAT_CHAR_STAR_AS_STRING` with Catch2?

Tags: c++, catch2

The [doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) C++ test framework has a [`DOCTEST_CONFIG_TREAT_CHAR_STAR_AS_STRING`](https://github.com/doctest/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/configuration.md#doctest_config_treat_char_star_as_string) configuration option. This option allows me to write

```cpp
char * tls_password;

// ...

CHECK(tsl_password == "swordfish");
```

That is, use `==` to compare C strings without having to use the more verbose C-style

```cpp
CHECK(strcmp(tsl_password, "swordfish") == 0);
```

How can I achieve the effect of `DOCTEST_CONFIG_TREAT_CHAR_STAR_AS_STRING` in Catch2? That is, have boilerplate-free assertions that compare to C-style string constants.

Comment: IMO it is better to: `using namespace std::literals` (or more specific version) and then just use suffix int check: `CHECK(tsl_password == "swordfish"sv);`. Changing behavior of build in operator is a code smell. Or Better use matcher: `CHECK_THAT(tsl_password, Equals("swordfish"));`

Comment: @MarekR What do I do when I want to compare two `char *` variables? Create std::string from one of them? Btw, if you post your comment as answer, I'd accept it

Comment: `std::string` has `operator==` for handling `const char*` so one side, so it is enough to do conversion for one argument. Also if you use C++17 `std::string_view` is cheaper.